# Is this from a bot attack?

Tags: php, security

I checked the error_log today and found this suspicious:

```
    [Mon Nov 27 01:18:36 2011] [error] [client omitted] 
    File does not exist: /var/www/domain.com/htdocs/robots.txt
    [Mon Nov 27 01:18:45 2011] [error] [client omitted] 
    File does not exist: /var/www/domain.com/htdocs/robots.txt
    [Mon Nov 27 01:24:38 2011] [error] [client ommited] 
    script '/var/www/domain.com/htdocs/proxy-1.php' 
    not found or unable to stat
    [Mon Nov 27 01:24:57 2011] [error] [client omitted] 
    script '/var/www/domain.com/htdocs/judge112233.php' 
    not found or unable to stat
```

And I say suspicious because I am the only person using the site right now, so I know all the pages and I would never access those pages above. So is this a bot attack?

Comment: @jamewaffles sorry will think about it before posting.

Comment: No problem. Just some advice for future reference :-)

Comment: FYI, these are very common.  They are of no concern... just bots looking for scripts that may have been uploaded to your server for remote control.  You only need to be concerned if any of these requests succeed.

Answer (score 5):

Looks more like a web crawler to me.

Comment: this is the first time i have seen this so i have been panicking.  what does that mean?

Comment: Normally it means that Google is looking through your site, adding the pages to its index. Of course, it could be other search engines. Try looking up the IP address and/or the User-Agent header.

Comment: this is one the IPs:  58.218.199.147

Comment: That IP is a bad IP. http://www.ipillion.com/ip/58.218.199.147 does not look too legit.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 first could be a crawler for search engines attempting to get data from [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_protocol)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at useragent, it's good to check the IPs you find as well.  I've sen DOS attacks with spoofed googleBot useragent headers.  the version 6.66 kinda gave it away, but it didn't *have* to.

Answer (score 0):

Reading some of those comments on ipmillion found this:

```
 These machines are not Hackers/Crackers at all,they have merely been 
 Compromised.A scan of several of these ip blocks reveals that the 
 Machines are not Fire walled or running any kind of Security.
 They have basically been hijacked and are now being used as D
rones,ie BOTNETS. As for the people who have Compromised them!! 
They could be any were in the World.
```

So i guess you have nothing to worry about.